# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>'

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I am new to asynchronous programming, so after going through some async sample codes, I thought of writing a simple async code

I created a simple Winform application and inside the Form I wrote the following code. But its just not working

```
private Task<string> methodAsync() {
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    return "Hello"; //Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>'
}

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = await methodAsync();
    MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```

Could someone please put some light here..

Answer (score 166, accepted):

The listed return type of the method is `Task<string>`.  You're trying to return a `string`.  They are not the same, nor is there an implicit conversion from string to `Task<string>`, hence the error.

You're likely confusing this with an `async` method in which the return value is automatically wrapped in a `Task` by the compiler.  Currently that method is not an async method.  You almost certainly meant to do this:

```
private async Task<string> methodAsync() 
{
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    return "Hello";
}
```

There are two key changes.  First, the method is marked as `async`, which means the return type is wrapped in a `Task`, making the method compile.  Next, we don't want to do a blocking wait.  As a general rule, when using the `await` model always avoid blocking waits when you can.  `Task.Delay` is a task that will be completed after the specified number of milliseconds.  By `await`-ing that task we are effectively performing a non-blocking wait for that time (in actuality the remainder of the method is a continuation of that task).

If you prefer a 4.0 way of doing it, without using `await` , you can do this:

```
private Task<string> methodAsync() 
{
    return Task.Delay(10000)
        .ContinueWith(t => "Hello");
}
```

The first version will compile down to something that is more or less like this, but it will have some extra boilerplate code in their for supporting error handling and other functionality of `await` we aren't leveraging here.

If your `Thread.Sleep(10000)` is really meant to just be a placeholder for some long running method, as opposed to just a way of waiting for a while, then you'll need to ensure that the work is done in another thread, instead of the current context.  The easiest way of doing that is through `Task.Run`:

```
private Task<string> methodAsync() 
{
    return Task.Run(()=>
        {
            SomeLongRunningMethod();
            return "Hello";
        });
}
```

Or more likely:

```
private Task<string> methodAsync() 
{
    return Task.Run(()=>
        {
            return SomeLongRunningMethodThatReturnsAString();
        });
}
```

Comment: how can I explicitly wrap `string` in `Task`? OR isn't there any way to return `Task` or `Task<T>` without using `async` and `await` in the method being called(methodAsync in this case)?

Comment: @Aniket No, you're wrong, there are plenty of ways of explicitly wrapping a string in a task.  I'll edit a solution in.

Comment: @Servy: suppose if I am not using the delay and some other code instead, which is causing the same delay in `methodAsync`, how shall I return the result string by wrapping it in Task?

Comment: You can use Task.FromResult to wrap a string in a Task.

Comment: @dotNETbeginner If you aren't `await`ing anything, or starting a new task, then you're blocking the current thread (which is the UI thread, given where you've called it) and you need to...not be doing that.  See second edit.

Comment: @Ameen That would be making the method synchronous, not asyncohronous, and would only cause further problems (namely the UI freezing).

Comment: @Servy: anyway I am `await`-ing in `button1_Click` then, how am I blocking the UI thread by not awaiting in `methodAsync`?

Comment: @dotNETbeginner Well, you can try it for yourself if you don't believe me.  `await` means, start that task, once it's started add a continuation to that task and continue on with the method where I left off once the async task finishes.  If you just used `Sleep` and then `Task.FromResult` in the async method it would spend the entire 10 seconds just starting the task, never returning back to the caller until it's completed, thus blocking the UI thread the whole time and effectively running the entire thing synchronously.

Comment: @Servy: its not the question of believing you.. by questioning I am trying to know something from you or trying to understand something which I am not able to or trying to get the questions clarified which are rising in my mind..Please don't misinterpret as I am doubting your answer..for that matter I have already accepted your answer..

Comment: @Servy ! you really know how to explain something. Great answer.

Comment: Task.FromResult is what I was looking for, so thanks.

Comment: With the 4.0 way of doing it (without using await) you can pass reference parameters.  
With `async` you cannot.

Comment: @GDavoli But you can't close over a reference parameter in a lambda, for exactly the same reason you can't use reference parameters in async methods, so it's not actually useful, it's just going to fail at a different place.

Answer (score 78):

Use FromResult Method

```
public async Task<string> GetString()
{
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
   return await Task.FromResult("Hello");
}
```

Comment: thanks this is exactly what I needed, which none of the other answers provided.

Comment: As far as I can tell this answer is the best way to implement an interface defined with a Task<T> with an implementation that is synchronous

Comment: Isn't it possible to avoid the "async" and "await"?
public Task<string> GetString()
{
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
   return Task.FromResult("Hello");
}

Answer (score 29):

Beyond the problematic use of `async` as pointed out by @Servy, the other issue is that you need to explicitly get `T` from `Task<T>` by calling Task.Result. Note that the Result property will block async code, and should be used carefully.

Try:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var s = await methodAsync();
    MessageBox.Show(s.Result);
}
```

Comment: While this may not be highly recommended, there was an instance where I wanted to get back `Task<string>` content within `catch {}`.  I couldn't `await` and `.ToString()` produced incorrect results.  This fit the bill.

Answer (score -2):

In my case.

```
        string ip = _GetStoreIpaddress().Result;


    private async Task<string> _GetStoreIpaddress()
    {
        string _store_iP = "";
        var Ip_address = await App.SQLiteDb.GetItemsAsync();
        if (Ip_address != null)
        {
            _store_iP = Ip_address.ToString();
        }

        return _store_iP;
    }
```

Comment: Firstly, this does not answer the question asked.
Secondly, this code has really a lot of issues. Very weird notation, which is not even consistent across this tiny method. Showing the Result() call as a part of solution is another big issue.

Answer (score -3):

```
    //source    
    public async Task<string> methodName()
            {
             return Data;
             }

    //Consumption
     methodName().Result;
```

Hope this helps :)