# Where and how to place await keyword

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm trying to understand how asynchronous works. This is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task<string> strReturned = returnStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("hello!");
        string name = await strReturned; //error: The 'await' operator can only be used 
                                         //within an async method. Consider marking this 
                                         //method with the 'async' modifier and changing 
                                         //its return type to 'Task'

        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }

    static async Task<string> returnStringAsync()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return "Richard"; 
    }
}
```

Any thing wrong?

Comment: So, what did you not understand what the error told you?

Comment: The error is there next to strReturned.

Comment: I saw that, but the error message explains very well what is wrong with what you tried. So what did you not get?

Comment: In an `async` method, you should use [`await Task.Delay(5000)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873.aspx) instead of `Thread.Sleep(5000)`.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14658001/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-string-to-system-threading-tasks-taskstring

Comment: Two things I see that are wrong. First, if you added the async keyword to the main method, it might even compile, but what do you expect it to do? When it hits the await keyword the whole method will unwind and the program will end. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens no,it won't compile

Comment: @280Z28, replacing Thread.Sleep with await Task.Delay solved the problem.

Comment: @Richard77: You may find my [async/await intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task<string> str = returnStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("hello!");

        string name = str.Result;

        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }

    static async Task<string> returnStringAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        return "Richard"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but it's pretty much the only case where it's a good idea to call `Result` (or `Wait()`) on an `async` `Task`. In most other cases, doing that would cause a deadlock.

Comment: @svick. Then give a better way to write this code. In fact, this is the very first time I've even written a code on async and await. Everything is still new to me in that field.

Comment: In this specific case (console application running `async` code), using `Result` *is* the right way. But in most other cases, it's not.