# HttpClient in c# http content

Tags: c#, post, httpclient

I am trying to send a json to a certain localhost site but somehow im not able to do it properly. Im getting an issue in the PostAsync line:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>' to 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage
```

I do not really know how to fix the conversion, thanks for any help.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    try
    {
        StringContent json = new StringContent(jsonText, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("http://www.localhost.com/", json);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseBody =  response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        // Above three lines can be replaced with new helper method below
        // string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);

        Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
        Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: `HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("http://www.localhost.com/", json).Result;`

Comment: You need to await the `PostAsync` call. Replace `client.PostAsync` with `await client.PostAsync(..)` and naturally, you'd need to add the keyword `async` to the caller method's signature.

Answer (score 0):

please try to add await to your  PostAsync and ReadAsStringAsync 
best regards .

Answer (score 0):

When executing asynchronous function calls you have to `await` task completion before getting actual return value of function.

Also please notice that when your method has at least one `await` you have to decorate your method with [async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) keyword.

Following is working example of your code snippet.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    try
    {
        StringContent json = new StringContent(jsonText, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://www.localhost.com/", json);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        // Above three lines can be replaced with new helper method below
        // string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);

        Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
        Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
    }
}
```

There are plenty of good Q&A's regarding async/await issue, one good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14658001/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-string-to-system-threading-tasks-taskstring).