# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>' in c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have this code

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //===========> Getting error here <==================//
        textBox2.Text = CallFunc(textBox1.Text);
    }

    static async Task<string> CallFunc(string str)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        string s = await p.DocumentToText(str);
        return s;
    }


public async Task<string> DocumentToText(string path)
    {
        string txt = String.Empty;
        AmazonTextractClient client = new AmazonTextractClient(key, Skey, reg);
        //some AWS functionality

        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        txt = "hello world";
        return txt;
     }
```

I changed this button1_Click function to

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var d = await CallFunc(textBox1.Text);
        textBox2.Text = d.Results();
    }
```

as was recommended by one answers of this question

[Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14658001/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-string-to-system-threading-tasks-taskstring)

but that still does not work

[image]

Comment: Do not use Thread.Sleep in an async method. Use await Task.Delay instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `async` in `button1_Click` event

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var d = await CallFunc(textBox1.Text);
    textBox2.Text = d;
}
```

Comment: error : string does not contain definition from "Result"

Comment: Use textBox2.Text = d;

Answer (score 1):

Use Async Task in button1_Click method

```
private async Task button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var d = await CallFunc(textBox1.Text);
    textBox2.Text = d.Results();
}
```